# How to use data entered into userform in main module

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I am very new to coding with VBA. I have a userform with five TextBoxes. The user will enter an integer in the first TextBox and cell locations (e.g. A1) in the last four TextBoxes. I want these data to be used in the main module. I need to use the integer in a loop, i.e. loop until a counter reaches that integer. I need to use the cell locations to begin accessing different datasets, which could be anywhere within the sheet.

I am having trouble accessing these data in the main module. I currently hide the form when the user clicks an OK button. To test  my code I am simply writing the data from the TextBoxes to cells.

The code from the main module:

```
 Sub Sort2Stack()

 UserInput.Show

 Cells(5, 22).Value = TestPeriod.Value 'integer entered in TextBox 1
 Cells(6, 22).Value = YMLoc.Value      'cell location entered in TextBox 2
 Cells(7, 22).Value = YFLoc.Value      ' .
 Cells(8, 22).Value = NMLoc.Value      ' .
 Cells(9, 22).Value = NFLoc.Value      'cell location entered in TextBox 5

 End Sub
```

I get a runtime error 424, object required. This is probably pretty simply and I have searched for a while--new to this.

Please advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(5, 22).Value = UserInput.TestPeriod.Text
```

I think you need to refer to your userform to get at the values. That's assuming you really did just Hide the form and not Unload it.  At the end of your procedure, before End Sub, you should

```
Unload UserInput
```

to get the form out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare public variables in your main module and access them from your form. You can set the variables equal to the current text of the textboxes on a specific button click event.